# Issues with homogen function in the climatol package of R

Tags: r

I am trying to homogenise a daily precipiation series data. I am using the homogen function with the expl =  TRUE argument. This function is supposed to return a few files including a pdf file with the exploratory data analysis of the data. However, the pdf i am getting in return only has 2 pages in it.

```
# Homogenisation: 
install.packages("climatol")
library(climatol)

#Set directory to work with
setwd("C:/Users/APF/Desktop/prec_data/data_trial_2")
dir()

#Preparing input files for climatol
daily2climatol("stations_data.csv",
               stcol= c(1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6), datcol = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
               varcli='RF', sep=',', na.strings='NA')

pdf("output.pdf")
homogen("RF", 1920, 2009, expl = TRUE)
dev.off()
library(here)
source(here::here('clihomog.R'))
```

I used this code. Initially i thought it might be an issue with the version of R i was using, or perhaps the package itself. But, it's now. as you can see in the code, I have tried using a different version of the climatol package itself. But it gives the same result, with or without the additional code wrapping in the developer's version.